# Git checkout branch without commit

Tags: git

I built a new file named test.txt in the master branch.
However,when I checkout into the test branch without commit it.
But I can also see it in the test branch

[image]

Why?

Comment: either u do git add or stash the changes

Comment: Untracked files are not under Git's management, so switching branches has no logical meaning for them.

Comment: In future, please include text output in your question instead of a screenshot to allow copy/pasting. Use the `{ }` (code sample) button to format it nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untracked files are left as they are when switching branches. To make *test.txt* part of the master branch (so that when you checkout the test branch it disappears), you need to add it using `git add test.txt` and commit using `git commit`.

If the untracked files were removed when you switched branches, they would be gone forever because they aren't committed. Git tries pretty hard to prevent that from happening.

Comment: solve it.thank you.I was use windows which reject my checkout branch when the changes hadn't commited.so It troubled me when I use mac.

Comment: @dredh, you may mark it as an answer if it helped you )

Answer (score 1):

when you run `git status` in master branch, it shows test.txt is a "untracked file", that means  test.txt is not under management of git, then what do you expect git do for you?

Comment: I was use windows which reject my checkout branch when the changes hadn't commited.so It troubled me when I use mac